# Linear equations in two variable based on digit word problems

Tags: linear-algebra

A two digit number is such that the product of its digits is 14. If 45 is added to the number the digits interchange their places. Find the number.

Comment: What have you tried ? . What two digits will give 14 ? Do you now have the answer ?

Answer (score 1):

Apart from @coincoin's method, we also can solve this question by a simple observation. The only two integers that, on multiplication, give the product as 14 are 2 and 7 or 1 and 14 but we don't take 1 and 14 since we want a two digit number. So either the number can be 72 or it can be 27(In the question it is mentioned that the number is a two digit number). If we add 45 to 27 we get 72 which is just the result we get by interchanging the digits of 27. So the number is 27.

Answer (score 0):

If $\overline{ab}$ represents your number, just translates this into a system of equations :

\begin{cases}
10.a×b &=14 \\
10.a+b+45 &=10.b+a \\
\end{cases}